# Difference between passing arguments VS apply with arguments

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, backbone.js, apply

I have a backbone collection, that uses a save mixin to do a Bulk save (just a utility method since backbone does not natively support bulk save)

```
// Cars collection
define([
  'Car',
  'BulkSave'
], function(Car, BulkSave) {
     return Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Car,
        save: function() {
            var options = {
                ...
                onSuccess: function(cars) {
                    // do something with cars
                    console.log(cars);
                }
                ...
            };

            this.bulkSave(options);
        }
     }).mixin(BulkSave);
});
// BulkSave Mixin definition 

define([], function(){
    return {
        save: function(options){
            var thisCollection = this;

            $.ajax({
                type: options.type,
                url: options.url,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(options.data),
                success: function(data) {
                   // data would give me the list of cars
                   // that changed
                   options.onSuccess.apply(thisCollection, arguments); 
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

So when I want to a bulk save of the collection, I would be calling

```
cars.save();
```

The question I had here was in the `success` callback of the `ajax` method, I will be calling the `onSuccess` method available in the options object to which I will be passing in the arguments.

What is the different between

```
options.onSuccess(arguments);
// this logs an arrayList of 3 properties
// [0]  -- the actual list of cars which changed
// [1]  -- 'success'
// [2]  -- the xhr object
```

**vs**

```
options.onSuccess(thisCollection, arguments);
// When i do this instead 
// it logs
// the list of cars that changed instead
```

Can someone explain the difference between the 2 scenarios ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example you just pass the arguments object to that function.

In the second one, you invoke the function using [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). In short, the apply function calls the function with "spread" arguments. That means the your function is called like yourFunction(arg0 /* where arg is a single element from arguments */, arg1, argN, ...) with given "this". For more see the page I pointed out.

Comment: You mean to say that, if my function has 3 arguments, the apply would work as follows

`onSuccess: function(cars, successString, xhr) {  }` where in I can access each arg inside the method ?

Comment: Yes, indeed.  You will get 3 arguments passed and you can access them easily as you would call option.onSuccess(car, successString, xhr).

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for clearing my doubt :)